# SSRS05 A one page report in preview shows a second page with only footer in print layout

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a user sign off report where it shows a users rights/access to the system which all fits nicely onto one page when I hit preview. However when I then go to print layout it shows me two pages with the second page only containg the footer.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the page size matches the paper size?

If so, have you tried setting the page footer's PrintOnLastPage property to false? Then again, if you really need that footer to be there (seeing that there's only one page), you might have to try fiddling with the margins to get it to fit within the first page.

Answer (score 1):

The report size at design time, plus the margins must be less than the paper size. Sometimes you can have a report that is too wide that is essentially generating a blank page "to the right" rather than underneath the first page.

Comment: For example, I found for a 8.5 inch wide sheet of paper, with 1 inch margins, my report width had to be less than 6.5 inches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have scrunched it all up so that it is WELL within the page size and I have tried all combinations of Footers (and headers).

It is a slightly wierd report in that it has fields that need to grow to show all the information and a small table too, but even at full growth the data looks like it fits on one page (in preview in Visual Studio) but as soon as it goes to print preview and printing it reverts to two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have extra area to the right of the last field of the report.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've adjusted the report's display size in the property sheet, too?

Hope this helps,

Bill